# How can I do multiple pandas dataframes samples iterating over a dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary like this:

```
 dic= {'AGS': array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64),
'CM': array([1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64),
'COA': array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int64),
'COL': array([1, 2], dtype=int64)}
```

And a dataframe like this:

```
c = pd.DataFrame(data={'CTY':['AGS', 'AGS', 'AGS', 'AGS', 'AGS', 'AGS', 
                          'AGS', 'AGS', 'AGS', 'CM',  'CM',   'CM', 
                          'CM',  'COA', 'COA', 'COA', 'COA', 'COA', 
                          'COA', 'COA', 'COL', 'COL'],
                   'DIST':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 
                         1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2],
                   'FA':[350, 320, 350, 360, 380, 380, 480,480,488,
                         780, 320, 310, 250, 141, 564, 564, 437, 438,
                         287, 287, 560, 560],
                   'ID':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
                         3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2],
                   'LTT':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C',
                          'C', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'E',
                          'S', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A',
                          'C', 'A', 'E', 'S']
                   })
```

What I have in mind is maybe use the dictionary to iterate over the dataframe in some way and then generate what I really need that is a sample that depend on the filtered `CTY` and `DIST` columns as I write below and then do I concat of those results:

```
    df1=c[(df['CTY'] == 'AGS') & 
   (df['DIST'] == 1)].sample(n=2)
    df2=c[(df['CTY'] == 'AGS') & 
   (df['DIST'] == 2)].sample(n=2)
    df3=c[(df['CTY'] == 'AGS') & 
   (df['DIST'] == 3)].sample(n=2)
    df4=c[(df['CTY'] == 'CM') & 
   (df['DIST'] == 1)].sample(n=2)
    df5=c[(df['CTY'] == 'CM') & 
   (df['DIST'] == 2)].sample(n=2)
               .
               .
               .
    dfn=c[(df['CTY'] == 'COL') & 
   (df['DIST'] == 2)].sample(n=2)  

    pd.concat([df1,df2,df3, df4, df5, dfn])
```

What ideas do you have?. I would like to get the fastest output as possible, I would appreciate it. Maybe with a list comprehesion

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you may need a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {key: c[c['CTY'].eq(key) & c['DIST'].isin(set(val))].sample(n=2) 
     for key,val in dic.items()}
```

---

Post this you can access each key to access the dataframes:

Example:

```
print(d['AGS'])

   CTY  DIST   FA  ID LTT
3  AGS     2  360   2   B
1  AGS     1  320   1   A
```

For concating:

```
pd.concat(d) #this will keep the identifier
```

or

```
pd.concat((c[c['CTY'].eq(key) & c['DIST'].isin(set(val))].sample(n=2) 
           for key,val in dic.items()))
```

Comment: It could be but what I want is to get  2 samples for each unique number in dict related to its key

Comment: @Richard21 thats what it does, try the code which defines `d` then try `pd.concat(d)` , this is the replication of your dummy code

Comment: @Richard21 or try the last block of code if you don't want the keys

Comment: Yes I've treid but I still desire an output that samples n=2 for each unique value of DIST. I mean, the expected output it will be 4 rows just for the values 1 and 2 in the DIST column @anky